# How can I set background colour for top section in iPhoneX

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9, iphone-x

I just realise that my app is not working for iphoneX's design. I have a UIVIew (containing textfield and button) tends to be like navigation bar so it does support for iPhone 8 and 8 plus. However, the iPhoneX has blank white for the top section. Vice versa, if I set the Uiview to act like navigation bar, then the iphone8 and 8plus will have higher gap between the textfield and top layout. May I know how can I set the constraint that fits for all version or other way to add for the top section and it also changed when landscape mode. Many thanks!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeRa9.png)

Comment: In whole app you used navigation bar. so, it display perfect.

Comment: interface builder or code?

Comment: I wanted to have a long textfield with a button on top act like navigation bar... but if I using navigation bar so the size doesnt fit at all...

Comment: @Lu_ by using storyboard... and I realise for the error "safe area layout guide before iOS 9" only workable for iOS 9 and above. too bad my app is from 8.0 above, in case I need to upgrade the deployment target? or just unchecked the safe area layout?

Comment: like in ansver, safe area should work, or you would have to adjust your constraints and heigh when you detect iphone X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Interface Builder you may want to update your constraints and their settings.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     if UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.safeAreaInsets.top > CGFloat(0.0) {
         topConstraint.constant += 24
     }
 }
```

or

[image]

Comment: for the topConstraint is my UIView's top constraint when detected is iPhoneX?

Comment: it will be a constraint for your textfield. The rest should be on top if is not relative to safe area. And overal height should be increased

Comment: hi, please check i appended screenshot at my post, so u mean i have to put top constraint for UIview's top, textfield's top and my button's top ? increase 24 pixels more?

Comment: yes, that is what i believe would work for you, safe space margin does not work for me but this does

Comment: Hi, i tried today, its not working if i checked the safe area layout guide. Can i just change the colour for status bar ?